# Constant values in Neo4j Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to be able to tidy up some longer cypher queries that I'm using in the neo4j console.

In the spirit of the Pretty graphs page in the neo4j documentation, choosing an arbitrary example, say I have the query to create a complete six node graph, K_6:

```
foreach (x in range(0,5) | create (n:Node {val: x}))
with *
unwind range(0,5) as x
with x
unwind range(0,5) as y
match (n:Node), (m:Node) where n.val = x and m.val = y and n.val <> m.val create (n)-[:X]->(m)
```

Ideally I'd be able to take out the five in the `range(0,5)` and replace it with a constant expression like `NODE_COUNT` for `range(0,NODE_COUNT)`.

Are comments the only way to improve the legibility of a query such as that above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can even take out the whole range,

I usually do that by prefixing the query with a `WITH` statement.

So either:

```
WITH 5 AS node_count
foreach (x in range(0,node_count) | create (n:Node {val: x}))
...
```

or even

```
WITH range(0,5) AS node_range
foreach (x in node_range | create (n:Node {val: x}))
...
```

Comment: I like it :) thank you very much, I will need to reread the with documentation